# jQuery slideToggle with multiple divs

Tags: jquery, html, slidetoggle, jsfiddle, slideup

I'm trying to slideToggle with multiple divs, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I've gotten the basic functionality of what I want in a 2 div layout:

http://jsfiddle.net/q6smW/

```
$(".replication").slideUp(500,function(){
    $(".duplication").slideToggle(500)
});
```

But I need it to work with 3 or 4 divs instead of just 2.

I almost feel like the code should be similar to this:

```
$(".replication").slideUp(500, function($(".duplication").slideUp(500,function()){    
     $(".thirdclass").slideToggle(500)
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest wrapping your image divs in a container, and doing the same to your info divs. Either you use the same container or two separate--up to you. Then use when an image div is clicked, hide all your info divs, and show only the corresponding info div, by way of using the index of div relative to the container. You can use jQuery's index() function. It also simplifies your code.

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: @NateBradshaw, my solution is actually similar to Moby's. So I'm curious about your comment to his solution. If you follow the same pattern when you add your new menu item, it should work with either of our solutions.

Comment: Frank, please bear with me as I'm pretty new to this. I'm trying my best to understand what is happening, but it just isn't making sense. Here is what I'm trying to accomplish: http://jsfiddle.net/dWUry/3/ I have added a new menu item that looks exactly like the other two, but the functionality of slideToggle is lost. I wish to keep this functionality, as seen in my first Fiddle. Is this possible?

Comment: I think I know what you mean: the slide effect looks inconsistent. If you want to make the slide consistent so that it slides up when hiding and then slides down when showing, you can check this: http://jsfiddle.net/JZ86W/2/

Comment: Frank, close enough! I just need to figure out how to allow each item to be toggled off individually. Going from item to item is awesome with your solution, except for toggling off. Thanks so much!

Comment: Hi @NateBradshaw, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/frankfajardo/JZ86W/7/. Basically, that will hide the info if the corresponding image is clicked the second time. Also, there is a commented line which you can use instead if you do not want the info to disappear if the same image is clicked. (See comment in the code).

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, Frank! You rock.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to make everything generic to handle it with common ground.

Firstly, I would alter your markup to be something like this, note the data attributes:

```
<div class="dupImage img" data-menu="duplication"><img /></div>
<div class="repImage img" data-menu="replication"><img /></div>

<div class="menuitem" id="duplication">
    <h3>Duplication</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>CDs, DVDs or Blu-Rays</li>
        <li>CDs, DVDs or Blu-Rays</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="menuitem" id="replication">
    <h3>Replication</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>CDs, DVDs or Blu-Rays</li>
        <li>CDs, DVDs or Blu-Rays</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then condense your script to something like this:

```
var menu;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.menuitem').hide();
    $('.img').click(function () {
        menu = $("#" + $(this).data("menu"));
        $(".menuitem:not(#" + menu.attr("id") + ")").slideUp(500,function(){
             menu.slideDown(500);
        });
    });   
});
```

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/MXusL/1/

I hope this helps, good luck with your app!

Comment: awesome, but when I add a third menu item, the functionality completely changes. this is not desired, as i wish to keep the same slideup/slidedown toggle functionality.

http://jsfiddle.net/MXusL/2/

Answer (score 0):

Based on Moby's answer small improvement so that you can toggle active one , otherwise you cant close it once it is open.

http://jsfiddle.net/jhYq5/2/

```
var menu;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.menuitem').hide();
    $('.img').click(function () {
        menu = $("#" + $(this).data("menu"));

        $(".menuitem:not(#" + menu.attr("id") + ")").slideUp();
        menu.slideToggle();


    });
});
```